# communicate with web database with android

Tags: php, android, http-post, webservice-client

I have a signup form in a android app which consist of a username and a password. I want that when a user click the submit button of the signup form then the username and password will be saved into a web-database(mySql database).

When a user press submit button then `sendPostRequest(givenUsername, givenPassword);` is  executed.

and sendPostRequest() function is like that

```
private void sendPostRequest(String givenUsername, String givenPassword) {

    class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String paramUsername = params[0];
            String paramPassword = params[1];

            System.out.println("*** doInBackground ** paramUsername " + paramUsername + " paramPassword :" + paramPassword);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();


            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/imon.php");



            BasicNameValuePair usernameBasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("paramUsername", paramUsername);
            BasicNameValuePair passwordBasicNameValuePAir = new BasicNameValuePair("paramPassword", paramPassword);


            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairList.add(usernameBasicNameValuePair);
            nameValuePairList.add(passwordBasicNameValuePAir);

            try {

                UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList);

                httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

                try {

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);


                    InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                    while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                        stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                    }

                    return stringBuilder.toString();

                } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                    System.out.println("First Exception caz of HttpResponese :" + cpe);
                    cpe.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.out.println("Second Exception caz of HttpResponse :" + ioe);
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                System.out.println("An Exception given because of UrlEncodedFormEntity argument :" + uee);
                uee.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result.equals("working")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HTTP POST is working...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid POST req...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }           
    }

    SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(givenUsername, givenPassword);     
}
```

And my imon.php is like that:

```
 <?php

 $varUsername = $_POST['paramUsername'];
 $varPassword = $_POST['paramPassword'];

 if($varUsername != "" && $varPassword != ""){

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
 if (!$con) {
die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
 }

  // make foo the current db
  $db_selected = mysql_select_db('post_db', $con);
  if (!$db_selected) {
   die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $sql="INSERT INTO post_table (username,password)
 VALUES
  ('$varUsername ','$varPassword')";

   if (!mysql_query($con,$sql))
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
     }

echo 'working';
  }else
       {
   echo 'invalid';
       }
   ?>
```

But data is not inserted into my-sql database.

What am i wrong here??
What should i do to insert the data of signup form into web database??

Comment: I'd try replacing the $_POST[] vars with a $_GET[] and manually try it in a browser to debug it. By the looks of your code, it could be failing for any reason.

i.e. imon.php?paramUsername=someone&paramPassword=something - And then see what the output is. If it works, then you know its not the php. As an aside, the PHP looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
```

and then do this

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
```

mysql and mysqli are separate extensions. you can't share resources from one with another.

mysqli_query() and mysql_query() doesn't take the same param order. the first param of mysql_query() is the query. where in mysqli_query first parameter is the connection resource. You were also intermixing the connections earlier as well.

Comment: i corrected this as if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)) but still didn't work @DevZero

Comment: you can't correct it as `mysql_query($con,$sql))`. just do `mysql_query($sql)`

Comment: It worked but still i don't understand what was my wrong.Can you explain me this as details.